# Two CardViews side by side

Tags: android, xml, margin, android-cardview

Good afternoon,

What is the best way to put two CardViews side by side (on the same line), with a margin between both of them?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey @D. Math, did the answer below help?

Comment: Yes it helped a lot, thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a LinearLayout with orientation horizontal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_viewLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_viewRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What about the margin between the two?

Comment: Dual margins is one way.. Another is an empty `<View>` between the two with a set width.